# Implement a Finite State Machine using function pointers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, state-machine

I am trying to implement an **FSM using function pointers in C**. [image: This is the state machine which I have to implement]

1. The state machine must be using function pointers.
2. When the system gets into a state, say for eg: Drive, It can print Current State is driving.
3. The main program will have an API to set the current state like SetState(DriveModeEnum)

Although I have tried my version, **I would like to know if there are any other optimized ways where I can implement this**? Kindly let me know your approach. Please mind that there might be some errors in the logic. Using `scanf` assuming that the inputs could be from anywhere such as CAN message or some global variables in an embedded system.

Trial code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

enum driveState_t
{
    PARK = 0,
    NEUTRAL = 1,
    DRIVE = 2,
    REVERSE = 3,
    SIZE
};

enum driveState_t park_to_xxx(enum driveState_t targetState);
enum driveState_t neutral_to_xxx(enum driveState_t targetState);
enum driveState_t drive_to_xxx(enum driveState_t targetState);
enum driveState_t reverse_to_xxx(enum driveState_t targetState);

enum driveState_t (*nextState[])(enum driveState_t) = 
{
    park_to_xxx,
    neutral_to_xxx,
    drive_to_xxx,
    reverse_to_xxx
};

enum driveState_t currentState;

int main()
{
    static enum driveState_t targetState;    
    currentState = PARK;
    targetState = NEUTRAL;
    printf("\n Starting State Machine at currentState %d Target State %d", currentState, targetState);
    while(targetState != 0) // not PARK
    {
        targetState = (*nextState[currentState])(targetState);
    }
    printf("\nExiting State Machine at Currnet State %d\n", currentState);
    return 0;
}


enum driveState_t park_to_xxx(enum driveState_t targetState) // Park is 0
{
    if(targetState == 1)
    {
        printf("\n Park to xxx - Current State is %d, Target State is %d\n", (int)currentState, (int)targetState);
        currentState = targetState;
    }
    else if(targetState == 0)
    {
        printf("\n Park to xxx - Current State will remain %d", (int)targetState);
        currentState = targetState;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Park to xxx - Invalid State, Current State will remain %d", (int)currentState);
        currentState = currentState;
    }
    
    printf("\nEnter next state :");
    scanf("%d", &targetState);
    return targetState;
}

enum driveState_t neutral_to_xxx(enum driveState_t targetState) // Neutral is 1
{
    if((targetState == 0) || (targetState == 2) || (targetState == 3))
    {
        printf("\n Neutral to xxx - Current State is %d, Target State is %d\n", (int)currentState, (int)targetState);
        currentState = targetState;
    }
    else if(targetState == 1)
    {
        printf("\n Neutral to xxx - Current State will remain %d", (int)targetState);
        currentState = targetState;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Neutral to xxx - Invalid State, Current State will remain %d", (int)currentState);
        currentState = currentState;
    }
        
    printf("\nEnter next state :");
    scanf("%d",&targetState);
    return targetState;
}

enum driveState_t drive_to_xxx(enum driveState_t targetState) // Drive is 2
{
    if(targetState == 1)
    {
        printf("\n Drive to xxx - Current State is %d, Target State is %d\n", (int)currentState, (int)targetState);
        currentState = targetState;
    }
    else if(targetState == 2)
    {
        printf("\n Drive to xxx - Current State will remain %d", (int)targetState);
        currentState = targetState;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Drive to xxx - Invalid State, Current State will remain %d", (int)currentState);
        currentState = currentState;
    }    
    printf("\nEnter next state :");
    scanf("%d",&targetState);
    return targetState;
}

enum driveState_t reverse_to_xxx(enum driveState_t targetState)
{
    if(targetState == 1)
    {
        printf("\n Reverse to xxx - Current State is %d, Target State is %d\n", (int)currentState, (int)targetState);
        currentState = targetState;
    }
    else if(targetState == 3)
    {
        printf("\n Reverse to xxx - Current State will remain %d", (int)targetState);
        currentState = targetState;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Reverse to xxx - Invalid State, Current State will remain %d", (int)currentState);
        currentState = currentState;
    }     
    printf("\nEnter next state :");
    scanf("%d",&targetState);
    return targetState;
}
```

EDIT: My code is compilable and tested. If you are sharing your code too, requesting you to share the compiled one. The reason is that I want to compare the parts where the duplicate code can be removed or corrected and also check how much the code can be optimized in any way. I shall take this as one of my learnings.

Comment: Why are you using literal constants like 1, 2, 3, when you could use the enumeration that you defined, e.g. PARK, NEUTRAL, DRIVE?

Comment: Can you use a structure, or an array of structures, to create a transition table? An FSM is basically a set of rules like: given current state X and input Y, move to state Z. In hardware, you can often implement one with just a programmable ROM — no need for a microcontroller.

Comment: @Caleb take a look at my posted answer, I think it does what your are suggesting. OP is really close, just a couple tweaks to get there. Overall I think this is pretty good (`#include <conio.h>` doesn't appear to be used, and once i got rid of that the posted code compiled cleanly and appears to work correctly).

Comment: @Caleb I forgot to remove the literal constants. Thank you for reminding me. Also, I got confused about the logic of how to implement using structures. One of the reasons why I have posted the question. Thank you for your reviews :)

Answer (score 2):

This is close to being what I would consider a canonical example of a FSM using function pointers. This is one of my favorite patterns for embedded C.

One suggestion:

What I like to do is define the `state` enum using a `typedef`and create a `struct` that holds a state and the pointer to it's service routine. Then the "StateMachine" becomes an array of those structures, and the code becomes a lot clearer when you are managing the transition between states:

```
typedef enum {
  DRIVE,
  NEUTRAL,
  REVERSE
} MachineState;

typedef struct {
  MachineState stateName;
  void (*stateFunc)(void);
} StateNode;

void drive();
void neutral();
void reverse();

StateNode* stateMachine = (StateNode*)malloc(NUM_STATES * sizeof(StateNode));
stateMachine[0] = {DRIVE, drive};
stateMachine[1] = {NEUTRAL, neutral};
stateMachine[2] = {REVERSE, reverse};

MachineState currentState = NEUTRAL;

void main() {
  while(1) {
    (*stateMachine[currentState].stateFunc)();
  }
}

void drive() {
  if(something) {
    currentState = NEUTRAL;
  } else if(something else) {
    currentState = DRIVE;
  } else {
    currentState = REVERSE;
  }
}
```

Also, I think you can get rid of `targetState` completely. Let each state naturally determine what the next state is, no need to haul around extra information to do that.

You might also consider adding a separate function that manages all of the user interaction in one place. You could call it in the main event loop before you call the next state routine.

Again, overall I think you're off to a very good start.

Comment: Thank you for your reviews. Although I am not a professional coder, it took me some sweet amount of time to develop this code. My question is, in State Machines like these, how do the states ENGINE-OFF and ENGINE-ON get handled?

Comment: @SAISRIKAR this is for sure a tricky design, it took me a while to understand it too. I wish I could remember where I first saw it to give credit, but it's been too many years to recall. I'm not nearly clever enough to come up with this one :)

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick glance through your code, and I see a few things that could be improved.

1. You define `driveState_t` but then use magic numbers (0, 1, 3, etc) for `targetState`.  Use the enums, it'll make the code much more clear, and also self documenting.  For example, you will no longer need the comment on this line: `while(targetState != 0) // not PARK`
2. The line `currentState = targetState;` is repeated 10 times or more, surely there is a better way to factor this so you don't have so much duplicated code (even if it is a simple assignment).
3. This also applies to the messages your code prints - there's a lot of duplication, consider combining them in some parameterized way.  Do the same for the user entry sequence involving the `scanf` call.

Comment: Thank you so much for your points. Although I am not a professional coder, it took me some time to develop it with some help. Even I thought of ways of getting rid of duplicated assignments. If possible, could you please suggest me so that I can keep this in mind and use this as learning in my future experiences? Thanks :)